# Partes da página de usuário em inglês

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Em algum momento, parte da página de usuário que estava traduzida foi revertida para o inglês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As páginas de usuários no meta apresentam o mesmo problema.

Comment: O esquema de tradução do site tá sendo bastante alterado e algumas coisas assim podem acabar acontecendo. Vou dar uma olhada pra ver se dá pra consertar agora ou se tem que esperar.

Comment: The same tabs, for some users, on other sites, are appearing in Portuguese (except for Activities, which is resolutely in English). http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286931/1927206

Comment: Consertado, uns dias atrás

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consertado há alguns dias, segundo o Gabe.